# updating content on iOS app without creating new version

Tags: ios

How do I update the content of an iOS app without having to create a new version each time? Does the newest version of swift/xcode have a way of doing that?

Comment: Keep the content in server and consume that through webservices. Above question is more related to app architecture and Xcode/Swift/Objective-c should not create much difference

Answer (score 1):

their are many ways you can do it first just put content on your server and fetch it according to your requiremnet also if needed you can store data on user disk (any type of data Videos sounds picture etc).

secondly you can use On-Demand Resources check out the guide below https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/